# Dell Optiplex 9020 won't POST

Tags: windows-10

I just installed windows 10 pro 64bit on My dell optiplex 9020 Intel core i7 desktop PC. The installation is completed and I also installed drivers and at  that time it was working properly.

I restarted it many times and it was working well, but the next day I powered it  and the PC is not working. It only shows orange led indication and beep sounds.

The code is 1 short and 2 repeatedly. There is no display, no keyboard and mouse. The power light is on but no bios screen appears. I tested the single strip of 4 GB 12800 memory in another MB board where it works succesfully.

Comment: Beep codes typically indicate hardware issues. You can look up what the beep codes are telling you here: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN143065/EN

Comment: @music2myear you should make that an answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Beep codes typically indicate hardware issues.

Installing an operating system doesn't normally cause hardware trouble, but it is not impossible for this to happen.

Look through this list and find the pattern that matches the beep tones you're hearing when you first turn the computer on. This will tell you where specifically the trouble is occurring.

- 1-1-2    Microprocessor register failure
- 1-1-3    NVRAM
- 1-1-4    ROM BIOS checksum failure
- 1-2-1    Programmable interval timer
- 1-2-2    DMA initialization failure
- 1-2-3    DMA page register read/write failure
- 1-3-1 through 2-4-4  DIMMs not being properly identified or used

I've only included the codes beginning with 1 beep, as you indicate your computer is making a code beginning with one. If you do not see the code your computer is making here, you may want to check out this link to see the rest of them: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN143065/EN

The Optiplex 9020 is a current model sold by Dell, and if you are indeed having hardware issue you should contact them for support on this issue.